# No realiza la consulta de rango de fechas en mi tabla-laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, table

Que tal compañeros estoy inicializando en laravel y mi problemas es que hago una consulta para que me muestre solo los datos por el rango de fecha mediante un formulario al momento de mostrar los datos en la tabla no me genera ni un cambio pero cuando lo ejecuto con dd($query) si me muestra solo los datos seleccionados
no se cual sea mi error agradecería su ayuda.

Mis Rutas

```
 Route::get('/procesos','Admin\ProcesosController@getProcesos')->name('procesos');
Route::post('/procesos','Admin\ProcesosController@postProcesosbuscar')->name('admin.procesos');
```

Mi controlador

```
 public function getProcesos(){
        $procesos = Procesos::with(['ent','tproces'])->orderBy('name','Asc')->paginate(15);
        $data = ['procesos' => $procesos];
        return view('admin.procesos.home', $data);
    }
    //buscar por rango de fechas
    public function postProcesosbuscar(Request $request){
        
        $fronDate = $request->input('fromDate');
        $toDate = $request->input('toDate');

        $query = DB::table('procesos')->select()->get()
                     ->where('fech_ini','>=',$fronDate)
                     ->where('fech_ini','<=',$toDate);
        $procesos = Procesos::all();
        //$procesos = Procesos::with(['ent','tproces'])->get();
        $data = ['procesos' => $procesos,'query' => $query];
        //dd($query);
        return view('admin.procesos.home', $data);
       
    }
```

Formulario con la tabla
estuve usando tabla de Bootstrap por defecto pero pensé que ese era el problemas así que instale CloudTables pero igual no me genera la consulta

```
 <form  action="{{route('admin.procesos')}}" method ="POST">
                  @csrf
                  <br>
                  <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="container-fluid">
                              <div class="form-group row">
                                  <label for="date" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Fecha Inicio</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" required/>
                                  </div>
                                  <label for="date" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Fecha Final</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="toDate" name="toDate" required/>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="search" title="Search"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/search.png"/></button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                </form>
  
                <!--Fin Busqueda por fechas-->
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table id="procesos" class="table table-striped table-bordered mt-4">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
                        <th>Fecha Fin</th>
                        <th>Numero del Proceso</th>
                        <th>Entidad</th>
                        <th>Tipo de Proceso</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th>Calificación 1</th>
                        <th>Calificación 2</th>
                        <th>Equipamento</th>
                        <!--<th>Bases</th>-->
                        <th>Gestión</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @foreach($procesos as $proceso)
                        <!--<tr @if($proceso->status == "0") 
                              class="table-warning"
                            @elseif($proceso->status == "1")
                                class="table-success"
                            @elseif($proceso->status == "2")
                                class="table-danger"
                            @endif>-->
                           <tr> 
                            <td>{{ $proceso->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{ $proceso->fech_ini}}</td>
                            <td>{{ $proceso->fech_fin}}</td>
                            <td>{{ $proceso->numberproces}}</td>
                            <td>{{ $proceso->ent->name}}</td> 
                            <td>{{ $proceso->tproces->name}}</td> 
                            <td>@if($proceso->status == "0") 
                                  Pendiente
                                @elseif($proceso->status == "1")
                                  Aprobado
                                @elseif($proceso->status == "2")
                                  Desaprobado
                                @endif
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <input class='toggle' type="checkbox" name='check-3'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>     
                              <input class='toggle' type="checkbox" name='check-3'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <a href="../uploads/{{$proceso->file_path}}/{{$proceso->equipament}}" target="_blank"><i class="fas mr-2 fa-file-pdf"></i>Ver PDF</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <div class="opts">
                                <a href="{{url('/admin/procesos/'.$proceso->id.'/edit')}}" class="btn btn-outline-success">
                                  <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="{{url('/admin/procesos/'.$proceso->id.'/delete')}}" class="btn btn-outline-success">
                                  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                </a>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                      @endforeach             
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

Comment: Me parece que no estás ejecutando la consulta, falta el `->get()`. Probablemente funcione con `$data = ['procesos' => $procesos, 'query' => $query->get()];`

Comment: creo que mi error esta en que en el la función postProcesosBuscar tengo $procesos = Procesos::all(); y por eso te trae todos los registros pero el problema es que si no lo pongo no me lista ningún registro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `query` lo tienes al revés, `get()` va hasta el final

```php
$query = DB::table('procesos')->select()
                     ->where('fech_ini','>=',$fronDate)
                     ->where('fech_ini','<=',$toDate)
                     ->get();
```

Como alternativa puedes usar

```php
$query = Procesos::where('fech_ini','>=',$fronDate)
                   ->where('fech_ini','<=',$toDate)
                   ->get();
```

y le puedes agregar el apuntador `all()` después del `get()`

```php
$query = Procesos::where('fech_ini','>=',$fronDate)
                   ->where('fech_ini','<=',$toDate)
                   ->get()
                   ->all();
```

Comment: la diferencia es que con get() le puedes agregar un apuntador where y va a funcionar, o algún otro apuntador y funcionará, a diferencia de all que lo que regresa es estático. En este caso la manipulación que haga de la variable $procesos no se verá afectada

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que estas haciendo mal es el retorno de la consulta a tu vista.

Prueba con esto
return view('admin.procesos.home', compact('procesos'));